# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' custom script

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a two-part script I called "bips.sh" and "chekdup.sh" a while ago when I tested it, it shows:

```
bips.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bips.sh: line 17: `fi'
```

here is the script:

```
---bips.sh---
#!/bin/bash -x
# find broadcast ip's that reply with 30+ dupes.

# i decided to make this script into two sections. when running this make
# sure both parts are in the same directory.
if [ $# != 1 ]; then
echo "$0 <domain - ie: college.edu>"
else
host -l $1 | grep 'has address' | cut -d' ' -f4 > $1.ips
cat $1.ips | cut -d'.' -f1-3 | sort |\
awk '{ print echo ""$1".255" }' > $1.tmp
cat $1.tmp | uniq | awk '{ print "./chekdup.sh "$1"" }' > $1.ping
rm -f $1.ips $1.tmp
chmod 700 $1.ping
./$1.ping
rm $1.ping
fi
```

second part of the script

```
---chekdup.sh---
#!/bin/bash -x
# this checks possible broadcast ip's for a given amount of icmp echo
# replies.
ping -c 2 $1 > $1.out
if
cat $1.out | grep dupl > /dev/null
then
export DUPES="`cat $1.out | grep dupl | cut -d'+' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1`"
else
export DUPES=1
fi
if [ $DUPES -gt 30 ]; then
echo "$1 had $DUPES dupes" >> bips.results
rm -f $1.out
else
rm -f $1.out
fi
```

Note: I updated the code and it always getting the error

Comment: Script `bips.sh` does not contain 17 lines. I suppose it contains something more at the end. It is full with unnecessary `cat file | sometool ...` snakes. Not needed! Use `sometool file` or `sometool <file` instead. The whole stuff could be done with one `awk` instead of using a lot of different utilities. This would use much less resources.

Comment: I added the comments to make it the original script.

Comment: Are you sure you got the line endings right?

Comment: I forgot to change the first line. I changed it to the original

Comment: For this kind of errors, please try to find a minimal version of your script that still leads to the error. Just remove lines that should not be relevant to the error and verify the error still exists. Doing so, most of the time allows you to find the cause of the error by yourself. If you still don't understand the error it allows you to ask much more precise questions. Please add a minimal version of your script to your question.

Comment: `if
cat $1.out | grep dupl > /dev/null
then` is not very good. What about `if [ $(cat ...) ]`?

Comment: @fedorqui: IMHO `if grep -q dup1 $1.out; then ...` is better.

Comment: There is no error in this script. It uses too much unnecessary utilities, but the syntax is correct. Try to remove some lines and You will be able to find where is fails.

Comment: A final idea. Try to see the output of `od -c bips.sh`. Maybe some bad character is in the file.

Comment: Properly indenting your code makes it much easier to find errors like this. It also makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It was so painful to read that code, I had to rewrite it

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# find broadcast ip's that reply with 30+ dupes.

if (( $# != 1 )); then
    echo "$0 <domain>"
    echo "example: $0 college.edu"
    exit
fi

host -l $1 |
awk '
    /has address/ {sub(/[0-9]+$/, "255", $NF); ips[$NF]}
    END {for (ip in ips) print ip}
' |
sort |
while read ip; do
    dupes=$( ping -c 2 $ip | grep -oP 'dupl.*\+\K\S+' )
    if [[ $dupes && $dupes -gt 30 ]]; then
        echo "$ip had $dupes dupes"
    fi
done >> bips.results
```

Comment: I tried the code but now it shows:
    bips.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
    bips.sh: line 21: `done >> bips.results'